Anthology TV mini series soft-hard sci fi, every story for itself, different humanoids
I am searching from years for TV show, anthology, mini series, soft-hard sci fi, every story for itself, no humans in the story, only aliens similar to human specie. Different episode different aliens. Somewhere 90-2000s
Anthology TV mini series maybe 6-8 episode max, American or Canadian or both.
Can't find it in any data base, list, thread in the internet or whatever.
I remember two episodes only, one was for aliens who travel and connects in space with spaceships traveling also to other planets, no idea about the plot, but that's about it, no idea about anything in the episode else, they look like humans, but no humans or planet earth is involved. Just like star wars, aliens who look like humans, different galaxy and solar systems.
The second episode I remember is about a family of science of four woman and one man, who on their planet, they look similar like humans, but with piggy noses and ears, invented a cure for All deceases, a serum, who drinks it, it is cured from everything. The society was in industrialization era. They made a planetary scale tv public presentation with all kinds of news stations, camera people around them and showed to other scientist and people how to made it at home for free, no money, business involved. All the planet doom them for been Satans as the cure will kill them other scientists said on news as the whole planet is connected at that moment, so all other people on the planet attacked them, basically the whole planet became crazy.
The family runs for the car, the brother of the four sisters is killed by the lynch crowd, the 4 gets in the car and runs for home, big house with garden, while the crazy people chase them. They get in their home fast and start to barricade all doors and windows, with wood plates and nails telling other members of their family, like cousins, uncles, etc. fast to help, while the crowd is trying to get them and kill them. They get in their science lab, the mobs get in the house, braking doors and windows and gets in the lab, the only thing they find is few empty glass bottles that contained the serum, but no one else to be found, as apparently the whole family drank the serum and disappeared. Maybe or not some countries on their planet lunched nukes at their home in that final moment. The end of the episode.

Can someone edit this question for spellings and grammar please? I'm finding it hard to follow
